# Enrich source data for use in a pivot table

Tags: microsoft-excel, office365, pivot-table

In Excel we use one worksheet, the `SourceSheet` where data from another system is copied into by my co-workers. The amount of rows can vary, the columns are always the same.
The data is used in multiple pivot tables located in the `PivotSheet`. Those pivot tables are used to show data in multiple pivot charts located in the `ChartSheet`.

One of the columns in the source is `Region`. In the workbook, I want to enrich the data with `Team` so the charts can show results per team. Each team supports one or more regions, you can think of it as the following mapping tables:

```
| Region | Team  |
| North  | Alpha |
| East   | Beta  |
| South  | Beta  |
| West   | Gamma |
| Center | Gamma |
```

How can I do that in a clean manner? I can't enter formulas (like lookup functions) in the `SourceSheet` because that will be copied over. Is there a way that pivot tables can use something like mapping/reference tables to transform or enrich data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it, even without the use of the PowerPivot add on.

1. Select the columns of the source table and make it a real table by selecting: `Insert > Table`. When you select the columns, you can copy new data in it without being bothered by the amount of rows.
2. Name the table by selecting the `Table Design` menu from the lint and edit the `Table Name` (`tblSource` for example)
3. Select the data of the reference table, make it a table too and name it. (`tblTeams` for example)
4. Select `Data > Relationships`
5. Add a relationship with the `tblSource` and column `Region` with the `tblTeams` and column `Region` (this can be different if you named them different).
6. Now you can insert a pivot table. As table enter `tblSource` (unfortunately there is no drop down`
7. When created, select the pivot table, the `PivotTable Fields` should show, other wise select `PivotTable Analyze > Field List`
8. From the data fields, select `More Tables...`
9. Select `tblTeams`. Now you can use the Team names in the Pivot table.
10. Additionally: If you want to use the data in a PivotChart and you only want to use the `Teams` data as selection data in a Slicer, drag the fields you want to use (Team) into the Filters field in the PivotTable Fields window.